# If Statement for Android TextView Message Display

Tags: java, android, if-statement, textview, settext

How do I create an `if` statement for the Android `setText()` command?

For example, if I have something like:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
TextView messageBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
phrase[0] = "Hello World!";  //
phrase[1] = "Toast";         // array is declared earlier in code
Random r = new Random();
int  n = r.nextInt(1);
messageBox.setText(phrase[n]);

if(/*condition when phrase[1] is displayed in messageBox*/){
   // do stuff
}
```

The idea is that I want to structure an `if` statement that monitors when a certain message is displayed in my `messageBox` object.

Comment: Use:

if(messgeBox.getText().toString().equals("Required text ")){
//then body of if statement
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView messageBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
    phrase[0] = "Hello World!";  //
    phrase[1] = "Toast";         // array is declared earlier in code
    Random r = new Random();
    int  n = r.nextInt(1);
    messageBox.setText(phrase[0]);

    if(messageBox.getText().toString().equals("Toast")){
       // do stuff
    }
```

Comment: In place of "Toast" you can also use phrase[1]

Comment: You can also say `if (n == 1) { //do stuff }`

Comment: I just did it with your substitute for phrase[1] before I read it and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @gamerguy0102 This is the correct answer. It may also help to know the `equalsIgnoreCase()` method, which will match texts ignoring capitalisation, and `trim()`, which will remove any blank spaces from either side of a `String`, before calling `equals()`

Comment: @gamerguy0102: Please mark as correct if my answer helped you.Thanks:)

Comment: I also like the n == 1 approach. Both turn out the same, but this is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if(phrase[n].equals(messageBox.getText().toString())){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
TextView messageBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
phrase[0] = "Hello World!";
phrase[1] = "Toast";
Random r = new Random();
int n = r.nextInt(1);
messageBox.setText(phrase[0]);

if(messageBox.getText().toString().equals("Toast")){
   //Write your code here when the result is Toast
} else {
   //Write your code here when the result is Hello World!
}
```